# PHP connected to (MySQL) database - does not input data

Tags: php, mysql, cloud9

I'm using Cloud9 to create a website. For whatever reason, the data taken from a HTML page will not get inserted into the Database.

I have tested to see if the Database is connected and it is. I would like to be able to get the data to be inserted into the Database.

The HTML code and PHP code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Add Record Form
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="../php/keithphp/address_submit.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="address_street">Street</label>
            <input type="text" name="address_street" id="address_street">
        </p>
            <p>
            <label for="address_street2">Street 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="address_street2" id="address_street2">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="address_city">City</label>
            <input type="text" name="address_city" id="address_city">
        </p>
        <p>
             <label for="address_county">County</label>
             <input type="text" name="address_county" id="address_county">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="eircode">Eircode</label>
            <input type="text" name="eircode" id="eircode">
        </p>
        <!-- <p>
            <label for="address_geo_latitude">Latitude</label>
            <input type="float" name="address_geo_latitude" id="address_geo_latitude">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="address_geo_longtitude">Longitude</label>
            <input type="float" name="address_geo_longtitude" id="address_geo_longtitude">
        </p> -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    *****************

    <?php
        $servername = getenv('IP');
        $username = getenv('C9_USER');
        $password = "";
        $database = "c9";
        $dbport = 3306;

        // Create connection
        $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);
        // Check connection 
        if ($db->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
        } 

        /*$address_id = $_POST['address_id'];*/
        $address_street  = $_POST['address_street'];
        $address_street2 = $_POST['address_street2'];
        $address_city    = $_POST['address_city'];
        $address_county  = $_POST['address_county'];
        $address_eircode = $_POST['address_eircode'];
        /*$address_geo_latitude = $_POST['address_geo_latitude'];
        $address_geo_longtitude = $_POST['address_geo_longtitude'];*/

        $sql = "INSERT INTO Address(address_id, address_street, address_street2, address_city, address_county, address_eircode, address_geo_latitude, address_geo_longtitude) VALUES ('$address_id', '$address_street', '$address_street2', '$address_city', '$address_county', '$address_eircode', '$address_geo_latitude', '$address_geo_longtitude')";

        $success = $db->query($sql);

        if (!$sucess){
            die("Could not enter data: ".$db->error);
        }

        echo "Thank you. Address submitted!"

        /*my$db->close();*/
    ?>
```

And the result after typing in test data is (no error message after text), I get;
Could not enter data:

Comment: Please visit http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Right now your code is really vulnerable and not safe at all. Your whole database could be hacked within a few seconds without any need of deeper knowledge of your system. Always use prepared statements when handling queries with user inputs.

Comment: It's for a college project, I have not asked about security, but thanks, I will look at that when I'm creating a "real-world" website.

Comment: Oh and btw: Your code fails because you've commented out the `$adress_geo_latitude` and `address_geo_longtitude` while you still have them in your query. That wont work ;) Altough you haven't asked about security, I think its always important to mention it. I can't know that you don't care about security since its only a school project. You can't imagine how many people would put such code online on a productive website.

Comment: They are both commented out in the HTML and PHP. (Also, honestly, I'm aware of the security issues, I'm literally just trying to get the Database working so I can progress and if needs be, provided the site gets traction and I'm willing to make it "real", I will add security then)

Comment: @StanislavAgapov `VALUES` is there... The problem are the two variables I've mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: what will happen likely is either you introduce a security breach in your school, either you'll forget to update your codes later and do it on your productions. This kind of "security" takes less thant 1 min and it's a habit you need to take, prepared statements are not hell to do. You'll be glad later to have these codes safe ready to copy

Comment: No they aren't. I see that you've commented out in HTML. I also see that you've commented out the variable definition. But you still use them in your `$sql` string. So you try to run a query with undefined variables. @Kaddath Exactly this. But there are so many people out here who are just like "yeye, I don't care, just give me solutions I'll look at it later" - and they'll never do it. Because they don't understand how easy it is to delete their whole database. And they, after few months they come back here again with posts like "my database got deleted what can I do"

Comment: @KeithFeeney even for school project, always think about security ! I always tried to destroy friend's databases when asked for a review (yep, rude..). Also, you should store your database connection in a specific file to include at the beginning of your pages and always check if `$_POST` is set before using it, because you're trying to insert data even when the form isn't submitted.

Comment: Oh, you mean in the actual SQL statement, ah, I see.

Comment: Again, I will look into that later, I'm literally very new to Cloud9, and after spending literally many hours trying to find out my issue (tutorials, videos, manuals), I needed an outsider(s) to see my error.

Comment: Yes, exactly there I mean ;) But keep in mind, if you take them out of the statement, be sure they can be `NULL` - otherwise you can't insert new data. And yeah its fine that you'll look at it later :) But please keep it in mind and do it. You can't imagine how many insecure websites there are on the web because of exactly this problem..

Comment: Yeah @Twinfriends, that's what I'm going to do.

Comment: Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: Glad we could help ;)

Comment: Well, no, i changed to null, and it still isn't working. Because it's a float (10,6)  value, I tried 0, and 1.234567, and still not working, same result

Would the address_id need to be included even though it auto-increments?

Comment: Figured it out, I was also missing a value from the database from the MySQL coding as well.

Comment: your `name="eircode"` and `$_POST['address_eircode']` don't match, so error reporting right there, would have thrown you an undefined index error. @KeithFeeney so this besides whatever else you found was breaking  your code.

Comment: @fred-ii, Tried fixing the eircode, and setting address_id to null (apparently it auto_increments itself?), still same error. (oh address_id is the primary key)

Comment: @KeithFeeney if `'address_id'` is an AI column, then change your `VALUES ('$address_id',` to `VALUES ('',` and not use the `$address_id` for the POST array; that should fix it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, no sadly, that didn't fix it, tried clearing browser's cache to see was that the issue, and same result. :(

Comment: Checked the database, inputs are going through, but still throwing an error. $success should be true. *looks at code* "success" is typed wrong in places.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks everyone! :)